# how to get post from other website put in to my wordpress post?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi all can anyone help me .I am a new wordpress. I want get post from other website put into my wordpress post .I try to search on google and youtube but I can not put post other site in to my wordpress site.
my wordpress site is http://mbl.myburgerlab.com.kh/ and other site is http://jaikon.blogspot.com/

Comment: We need more details to be able to help. Is the other website is a Wordpress website too? Does it have any RSS that you can fetch?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it would be to use some Post Importer Plugin(ex. "RSS Post Importer"). It would take posts from source sites RSS feed and repost them as new posts on your site.